# Sync local and remote database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

So I have finished writing this inventory project in django it includes a sales app I intend on having 2 version of the project one on local machine the other uploaded to heroku. In a situation were network won't be available (most time there is none) I want to use the offline version to print invoice and make sale. Later when the network kicks in I can sync it to the remote database to match the local database. I've read django sync-tool didn't get it that much I also read django multi database in the doc but I guess that is not suitable for what I intend to do. I also read django-replicated but seems to be mysql driven as I currently run my project using postgres. Thanks for any help in adv. And I am running django 2.1, python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much contemplating I decided to go with django-sychro https://github.com/zlorf/django-synchro

after updating it to be compartible with my django version